# Java script to close doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I build a toggle bar in html/css and I want to use JS to close. I think I did all the code right, yet the script does not work.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fa-times").click(function(){$(".sidebar_menu").addClass("hide_menu");
$(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_one");});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cebrvxnf/)

The point is that I created a button "x shaped" that closes the side bar but you won't be able to see it cuz is a custom font and I have no clue how to upload it onto jsfiddle. The button is placed in the top-right corner of the purple bar.

I hope its enough information and the code is easy to understand. I`m just at the start with html/css/js but I have to do this for a microsoft project since noone in my team can't even set a default html page.

P.S. Ignore the white element with that random text.

Comment: The code seems to work fine, I don't get why toggle_menu class is being used when there is no element with that class.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong,as ii saw you fiddle your code working fine.When user click on cross btn that time blue side bar hiding left side.

Comment: Exactly, but it doesnt work on my browser at least. I dont know. I check the browser console and nothing, no errors, no nothing.

Comment: which web browser you are using,i test your code on chrome,mozila.

Comment: and just add some dark color for your close btn

Answer (score 0):

Check width with element inspector in you browser

```
<i class="fa fa-times">you need same place holder here, or set width</i>
```

*EDITED*

[image]

Comment: You not say your browser name and version?

Comment: Its firefox, but i  tryed with edge and ie and i got the same results.

Comment: https://ifrimgeorge99.000webhostapp.com/ i put it here and yet no results

Comment: 404 your javascript file can not loadded:
`https://ifrimgeorge99.000webhostapp.com/js/menu.js`

Comment: Well, looks like I am the dumbest person ever. My code was <script src="js/menu.js"></script> instead of <script src="menu.js"></script>. So the scrips wasnt loaded. Not it works....